# Comparing Solution files from different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

When we do deployments with our build server, instead of deploying the solution file that has the projects with the desired changes, we deploy a *different* solution file that theoretically **should** be the same, but it is in a *readonly* state.

**Benefit**

- If the non-deployed solution file has changed dependencies or other major changes, since it is not being deployed, the build will fail, notifying everyone that there are major changes in the specific changeset, and giving attention to potential necessary changes to the *readonly* solution file

**Downside**

- Since developers are working on multiple versions of Visual Studio: 2012/2013/2015, it is a mess when trying to decide whether the build failed due to different versions of the **.sln** file *or* was it actually an *intended* major change to the solution.

**Is there a smart/structural way to compare the solution files, taking into account the Visual Studio version?**